# How to live detect elements height when window is resized?

Tags: jquery, height, padding, live

I have a fixed topbar on my site, and I'm adding a `padding-top` to the `body` element based on the topbar height.

`$('body').css('padding-top', $('.topbar').height());`

But when I resize window and topbar becomes heigher the above jQuery code is not working until I refresh the page on desired viewport.

How to detect the topbar height live, even when window is resized?

Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Another way to get the same is refreshing the page on window resize: $(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});

Comment: I need sth without refreshing the page, but thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a `.resize()` event. So you could try:

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {  

 $('body').css('padding-top', $('.topbar').height());

 });
```

If this doesn't work, make a fiddle and we can have a look at how your page is working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen for a resize event:

```
$(window ).resize(function() {
    $('body').css('padding-top', $('.topbar').height());
});
```